# My JPA throwing table or view does not exist error

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have strange problem. I have created read and write eclipse link data sources using weblogic server. i have defined them in persistence unit like this

```
<persistence-unit name="UnitRead" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/READ</jta-data-source>
<class>org.model.Employee</class>
<class>org.model.Department</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10" />
<!-- Logging level is set to INFO, Need to change in Production -->
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
<property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />
property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />      
</properties>
</persistence-unit> 
<persistence-unit name="UnitWRITE" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/WRITE</jta-data-source>
<class>org.model.Employee</class>
<class>org.model.Department</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> 
<properties>
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10" />
<!-- Logging level is set to INFO, Need to change in Production -->
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
<property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />
property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />      
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

here problem is if i give jdbc/read in place of write then it is working otherwise i am getting table or view doesn't exits.

very strange problem.

Comment: Did you point the data sources you created in weblogic at the same schema, and are they using the same login credentials?

Comment: i have created JNDI with the same names and my both read and write are different data schema and username and pwd are different. it is really strange to me.

Comment: If they are different schemas, that might explain why tables might be different within them.  Why are you using different user credentials?

Comment: sorry,I mean same schema but loded in to different environments with different usernames.

Comment: Can you see the tables using both logging credentials in other tools such as by directly accessing the database?

Comment: Yes.used sql developer. where as for once server i have access read and for another i have write levels.